# Why pass a parameters of multiple services to mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm new to asp.net mvc world mostly a windows developer moving to web. Be nice...

I found ridiculous when I look at many examples of asp.net mvc web applications that the pass to their controllers a list of services

Like this

```
public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService,
                IAnotherService anotherService,
                IYetAnotherService yetAnotherService,
                IYetAgainAnotherService yetAgainAnotherService,
                etc...
```

Would not be better to do something like

```
public CustomerController(IServices services)
{
}

public interface IServices 
{
    ICustomerService  CustomerService{get;set;}
    IAnotherServiceService  AnotherService{get;set;}
    IYetAnotherServiceService  YetAnotherServiceService{get;set;}       
}
```

Am I missing the obvious?

As anybody implemented the way I suggest in mvc4 or mvc5. I know mvc6 does it.
But I cannot use mvc6 at work.

Any samples using DI?

Thanks

Comment: If one monolithic service works for you, sure, you can do that. I tend to be injecting multiple dependencies, like email utilities, loggers, etc., in addition to my data services. You have to remember that a lot of DI frameworks use "service" as a blanket term for vastly different components.

Comment: Ok.you could have something like "IMyMvcServices" ,IFrameworkServices,rather than having a controller with 20 interfaces.To what gain? I am trying to learn here nothing else

Comment: Granularity. If every single one of your controllers has identical dependencies, and fulfilling those dependencies is possible, and *manageable*, with a "wrapper" service, then sure, go for it. You still have to configure how those services get injected into the wrapper, though, so you've just moved the complexity to another location. If you've seen an actual project with 20 dependencies to inject in a controller, there are deeper problems with that project than a wrapper can solve.

Comment: I think you make sense.Unfortunately the majority of samples all violates SRP ,and thinking now I agree with what you are saying,I just got fooled by so many sample out there with 10-15 interfaces passed to a controller. My suggestion does work when I have as you said many controllers that fullfill those dependencies.However mvc6 does go for the "IServicecollection" approach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing here is the fact that constructors with many parameters is a code smell often caused by that class having to many responsibilities: it violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

So instead of packaging the services to inject into a 'container' class that allows those services to be accessible using a public property, consider the following refactorings:

- Divide the class into multiple smaller classes.
- Extract logic that implements cross-cutting concerns (such as logging, audit trailing, validation, etc, etc)out of the class and apply those cross-cutting concerns using decorators, global filters (MVC) or message handlers (Web API). A great pattern for your business logic is the [command/handler pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).
- Extract logic that uses multiple dependencies out of the class and hide that logic behind a new abstraction that does not expose the wrapped dependencies. This newly created abstraction is called an [Aggregate Service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

Comment: Steven,thanks for your time and reply.Do you know any sample on codeplex,codeproject etcs where those patterns are put all together .I just want to see in code how it all hangs together.Many thanks

Comment: @developer9969: One project you can take a look at is [this one](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices). The project shows how to apply message based patterns such as command/handler and query/handler patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that for readability sake, even if you have multiple existing services which are also used in other applications, you could always wrap them in another class to avoid passing a long list of dependencies to the controllers.

Comment: that is exactly what I mean.I updated the question.What is there to loose by using my approach.It's easier to maintain does not break interface etc...

Comment: There's nothing to lose, as I said in my answer, if such wrapper makes sense for you don't hesitate to use it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have code in the API controllers that look like this:

```
public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService,
                IAnotherService anotherService,
                IYetAnotherService yetAnotherService,
                IYetAgainAnotherService yetAgainAnotherService,
...
```

That can be a code-smell and is an opportunity to refactor. But this does not mean the original code was a bad design. What I mean is in the API layer, we try not to clutter it with too many services that the controller is dependent on. Instead you can create a facade service. So in your example above, you refactor it to look like this:

```
public CustomerController(IServices services)
{
}

public interface IServices 
{
    ICustomerService  CustomerService{get;set;}
    IAnotherServiceService  AnotherService{get;set;}
    IYetAnotherServiceService  YetAnotherServiceService{get;set;}       
}
```

Which is good and then you can move the IServices to your service/business layer. The concrete implementation of that in the service/business layer will look like this:

```
public class AConcreteService:IServices {
public AConcreteService(ICustomerService cs, IAnotherServiceService as,  IYetAnotherServiceService yas)
{
         ...
}

public List<Customer> GetCustomers(){
   return _cs.GetCustomers();
}

public List<string> GetAnotherServiceData(){
   return _as.AnotherServiceData();
}

public List<string> GetYetAnotherServiceData(){
   return _yas.YetAnotherServiceData();
}
...
```

So that code will end up looking like your original code when implemented directly in the controller but is now in the service/business layer. This time it will be easy to unit test in the service class and the API layer will look much cleaner.